# PHP $_FILES empty on load

Tags: php

for some reason I can't get the $_FILES array to include the upload as selected on my form.  From what i have read the form looks ok, and all the other variables are received just fine.

Each time I submit the form the var_dump for the $_FILES array has 0 entries.

For this post i have removed the other fields for the sake of brevity since they are working.

```
<form name="addFact" id="addFact" action="add_fact.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateStatus();" >
    <input type="file" id="myImage" name="myImage" style="width:450px;"/><br />
</form>
```

And after I reload I use the following to check the $_FILES array:

```
echo "- Files - <br>\n";
echo "<pre>\n";
var_dump($_FILES);
echo "</pre>\n";
```

but the result is empty every time:

Files: 
array(0) {
}

**Update**
sorry, didnt realize validate status was still in there .. but this is the JS that checks whether to submit the form or not

```
function validateStatus() {
    jQuery("#addFact").validationEngine({scroll: false});
    var valid = $("#addFact").validationEngine('validate');
    if (valid == true) {
        submitForm('addFact');
    }
    return false;
}
```

Though I doubt that is part of the issue as the form submits successfully with all attributes still set including the file field , etc.

oh ..and lol .. another function .. :) ... here is the submt form function:

```
function submitForm(formName,message) {
    $.ajax({
        data: $("#" + formName).serialize(),
        type: $("#" + formName).attr('method'),
        url: $("#" + formName).attr('action'),
        success: function(response) {
            $('#load_target').html(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

load_target is the div on the index page I am loading this php file into with ajax. - hope that is all clear now :)

Also, to belay any conrens of the form not posting anything .. here are the results for the post var_dump

```
array(11) {
  ["action"]=>  string(4) "save"
  ["category"]=>  string(1) "3"
  ["startDate"]=>  string(10) "09-27-2012"
  ["expireDate"]=>  string(10) "11-27-2012"
  ["title"]=>  string(10) "Test Title"
  ["subtitle"]=>  string(10) "Test Title"
  ["include_image"]=>  string(3) "yes"
  ["img_loc"]=>  string(4) "left"
  ["img_size"]=>  string(2) ".3"
  ["scroll"]=>  string(1) "1"
  ["fact_text"]=>  string(27) "there's something about her"
}
```

Comment: are you actually uploading a file when you test it?  the index in $_FILES may not exist if the input field is left blank.

Comment: What's "validateStatus()" doing? Could it be manipulating that field?

Comment: validate status checks for all fields being populated (required fields that is) and then submits the form if all is good, sorry about that.

Comment: Yes i am selecting a file in the form field and submitting the form ... though tie $_FILES does not seem to reflect it.

Comment: From the [jQuery serialize documentation](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/): "Data from file select elements is not serialized."

Comment: now THAT is good info, Thank you .. now what do I do .. lol

Comment: perhaps ill make the file upload a lightbox and upload seperately without serializing .. then return the file name to the form and process it then .. I'll research a bit.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using jquery mobile add the data-ajax="false" to the form tag